# KCSPersistable with Swift Error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, kinvey, mbaas

I have researched this extensively.  After hearing the news about Parse the other day, I have been toying around with using Kinvey for my BaaS.  I am trying to save an object but I received an error related to KCSPersistable.

```
    class Event : NSObject{
      var entityId: String? //Kinvey entity _id
      var name: String?
      var date: NSDate?
      var location: String?
      var metadata: KCSMetadata? //Kinvey metadata, optional
     }



    func hostToKinveyPropertyMapping() -> [NSObject : AnyObject]! {
       return [
            "entityId" : KCSEntityKeyId, //the required _id field
            "name" : "name",
            "date" : "date",
            "location" : "location",
            "metadata" : KCSEntityKeyMetadata //optional _metadata field
             ]
      }
```

Swift calls it redundant to an NSObject due to the superclass.  I removed the KCSPersistable declaration and the code will build successfully, however now I receive the following error:

```
    'Object "<KinveyPractive.Event: 0x7fed18d484c0>" of type "KinveyPractive.Event" does not implement 'hostToKinveyPropertyMapping', a required 'KCSPersistable' method for saving the object to the backend'
```

I am running into a loop of issues. If I remove KCSPersistable, Xcode asks for it. However, if I leave it, Xcode won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you saw was because NSObjects in Kinvey implicitly implement KCSPersistable.

We've corrected our documentation to reflect this.
Please use the following sample in place of your code -

```
class Event : NSObject {

    var entityId: String? //Kinvey entity _id
    var name: String?
    var date: NSDate?
    var location: String?
    var metadata: KCSMetadata? //Kinvey metadata, optional

    override func hostToKinveyPropertyMapping() -> [NSObject : AnyObject]!     {
        return [
            "entityId" : KCSEntityKeyId, //the required _id field
            "name" : "name",
            "date" : "date",
            "location" : "location",
            "metadata" : KCSEntityKeyMetadata //optional _metadata field
        ]
    }

}
```